# In Xamarin.Forms, what is the simples way to display a list from a viewmodel in plain text?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

In a Xamarin.Forms application. I would like to have a View display a List of objects from the ViewModel in plain text. I have seen examples that use a list view like this.

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This method seems to work, but it doesn't allow me to use more than one object property in the TextCell. The example application that Visual Studio 2019 generates uses a CollectionView to do something more complex.

```
<CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                SelectionMode="None">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Item">
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                       LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                       Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                       FontSize="16" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                       LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                       Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                       FontSize="13" />
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"     
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

This method doesn't seems to work with my current ViewModel, though. Just using the existing code as an example, I have made something that looks like the following.

**Student.cs**

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Courses{ get; set; }
}
```

**Course.cs**

```
public class Course
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CourseNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**StudentDetailViewModel.cs**

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(StudentId), nameof(StudentId))]
public class StudentDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string studentId;
    private string name;
    private ICollection<Courses> courses;

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
       get => name;
       set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
    }

    public ICollection<Course> Courses
    {
            get => Courses;
            set => SetProperty(ref courses, value);
    }

    public string StudentId
    {
        get
        {
            return studentId;
        }
        set
        {
            studentId = value;
            LoadStudentId(value);
        }
    }

    public async void LoadStudentId(string sId)
    {
        try
        {
            var student = await DataStore.GetItemAsync(sId);
            Id = student.Id;
            Name = student.Name;
            Courses = student.Courses;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to Load Item");
        }
    }
}
```

I want the resulting page to display something like

```
Student Name
Courses:
   * CourseNumber - CourseName
   * CourseNumber - CourseName
   * CourseNumber - CourseName
```

When I try to use the ListView method, though, I can't figure out how to format the `Text="{Binding PropName}"` property of the TextCell so that I can use two properties in this "{Prop1} - {Prop2}" format. Using the CollectionView, I can't figure out how to properly bind the data to display it at all. What is the simplest way of displaying something like this, and what is considered the best practice for setting up my ViewModel to do this?

Comment: are you trying to display ONE student and their courses, or MULTIPLE students and the list of courses for each student?

Comment: @Jason In this case, I'm trying to list one student, and a list of courses with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a LOT of ways to approach this.  The simplest might be to use a `ViewCell` containting a `Label` with `Spans` instead of a `TextCell`.  You could also do something similar with a `CollectionView`, which does not require the use of `Cells`

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <Label>
                <Label.FormattedText>
                  <FormattedString>
                     <Span Text="{Binding Name}" />
                     <Span Text=" - " />
                     <Span Text="{Binding CourseNumber}" />
                  </FormattedString>
                <Label.FormattedText>
              </Label>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

the student info could be placed in a separate layout before the courses, or added to the courses' [ListView.Header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#headers-and-footers)

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly for me. I guess I just need to get more familiar with the types of cells and views that are available in XAML. You didn't put an end tag for <Label.FormattedText>, though. You might want to update your response for accuracy.